# Detecting which npm script command was run

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have an index.js file that can be run using the following scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "inspect": "firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  },
```

Is there any way that I can detect which command was executed in index.js file, so that I can initialize the method properly?

index.js

```
// if serve cmd
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://server.firebaseio.com'
});
//if deploy cmd
admin.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score 4):

NPM sets several environment variables when running scripts, including [`npm_lifecycle_event`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#current-lifecycle-event). This is intended to figure out if it's a `pre` or `post` script running, but can also be used for your purposes:

```
if (process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === "serve") {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://server.firebaseio.com'
  });
} else {
  admin.initializeApp();
}
```